# How to get the AWS EC2 Instance name using spring boot or any aws endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

Actually, I was looking to get the EC2 instance name,

[image]

I tried using **EC2MetadataUtils** class to get the metadata but in that response, the instance name is not there.
Could you please someone suggest any util class endpoint to get the name?

Comment: The name is just a tag. The tags are not available to the instance via the metadata, instead you would need to run a `DescribeInstance` and check the tags in its reponse.

Answer (score 0):

As luk2302 correctly states, the Name field is just a tag. The EC2 documentation has an example for how you can retrieve tags from the instance metadata:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#instance-metadata-ex-7

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Java code piece. **EC2MetadataUtils** does not currently allow to read tags by SDK.

```java
        Ec2Client ec2Client = Ec2Client.builder().build();
        String instanceId = "i-qqweqweqwe";
        DescribeInstancesRequest instanceRequest = DescribeInstancesRequest.builder()
                .instanceIds(instanceId)
                .build();

        DescribeInstancesResponse describeInstancesResponse = ec2Client.describeInstances(instanceRequest);
        if (describeInstancesResponse.reservations().size() > 0 && describeInstancesResponse.reservations().get(0).instances().size() > 0) {
            List<Tag> tags = describeInstancesResponse.reservations().get(0).instances().get(0).tags();
            Optional<String> name = tags.stream().filter(t -> t.key().equals("Name")).map(Tag::value).findFirst();
            if (name.isPresent()) {
                System.out.println(instanceId + " name is " + name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, 
I'm able to read the Instance name only with the Root user, getting exceptions when I use a different Role or User.
Exception: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: You are not authorized to perform this operation
I attached EC2 Full access policy, still didn't work.
Could you please let us know the which policy should we add to work?

Comment: AWS Java SDK load credentails from multiple provider. 
Order of that is EnvironmentVariable, SystemProperty, WebIdentityToken, Profile (~/.aws), Ec2Container.

If your EC2 instance has a role with EC2FullAccess, probably other credential providers with higher priority take precedence.